# How to apply function that returns Result to each element of HashSet in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a type defined as follows:

```
pub struct State<T: Clone + Eq> {
    pub db: HashSet<T>,
}
```

And I have a function that looks like the following:

```
fn check(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
   self.db.iter().for_each(|elem| elem.check());
   Ok(())
}
```

So I want to call `check` function for each of the element in `HashSet`. I just want to ensure that either all return `()` or there is some `Error` thrown. The above throws error as it expect `()` as output of `elem.check()`, but it returns `Result`. What's the proper way to handle this in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `(): FromIterator<()>`, it's actually quite ergonomic to short-circuit “collect” multiple `Result<(), E>` into another `Result<(), E>`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
pub struct State<T: Clone + Eq> {
    pub db: HashSet<T>,
}

/// Checks for equality to 0
fn check(x: i32) -> Result<String, String> {
    if x == 0 {
        Ok("yay, got 0".into())
    } else {
        Err(format!("whoops, got {} != 0", x))
    }
}

impl State<i32> {
    fn check(&self) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.db
            .iter()
            .map(|elem| check(*elem).map(|_| ()))
            .collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state1 = State {
        db: [0, 0, 0].into(),
    };
    let state2 = State {
        db: [0, 1, 2].into(),
    };

    println!("{:?}, {:?}", state1.check(), state2.check());
    // Ok(()), Err("whoops, got 1 != 0")
}
```

but it's not clear what advantage this offers over the imperative solution, which is much clearer.

```
impl State<i32> {
    fn check(&self) -> Result<(), String> {
        for x in &self.db {
            check(*x)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: One question, if instead I had two fields, `db_1` and `db_2`, then that with `collect` won't work, as it is not consumed, any ideas about it?

Comment: I think you would want to `std::iter::chain` the results of two checks.